# Is system.js adding stuff to my javascript?

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jqwidget

I am trying to get JQWidgets to work.  It has a jsxcore.js file that defines the following variable:

```
 var jqxBaseFramework = window.minQuery || window.jQuery;
```

Then in other files, this variable is used.  But I am getting an error that says `jqxBaseFramework is not defined` in the very next file.

I noticed that when I `system.import` a file, this added to the top of it:

```
  (function(require, exports, module, __filename, __dirname, global, GLOBAL) {
```

This causes variables that would be in scope to be out of scope.

Is system.js doing this?  **If so, Is there a work around to the scope issue?**

If not, I am going to have to go add that variable to the top of each file.... Not fun as there are quite a few.

Comment: Learn about CommonJS modules.  You should use `require()` / `import`, not globals.

Comment: @SLaks - This is not my code.  I do that in my code.  My code uses `import`.  But I need a way to get JQWidgets to load in my code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is system.js doing this?

Yes

> If so, Is there a work around to the scope issue?

Yes. SystemJS is a module loading system. You treat your files as encapsulated modules. You should throw away the concept of globals.

Should you want to expose a value from a module, you export it. Should a module need a value from a certain module, you require it. Read more about CommonJS to know more about how this mechanism works.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea.  And I do that in my code.  Alas, I don't own the code to JQWidgets, and can't find an alternative for a reasonable price.  Is there a way to pass this variable/value into the module/file without modifying it?

Comment: @Vaccano The quickest way would be to create a dummy module that exports it. Something like `module.exports = window.minQuery || window.jQuery;`

Comment: I am not a javascript expert, so I may be missing something here, but when the next file references `jqxBaseFramework`, it is still going to fail, right?  Because my export is not connected to that variable.

Comment: JQWidgets has an `jqx-all` file that loads just fine.  But it is **5.5 Megs** in size!  I like the idea though.  I think I am just going to home roll my own file.  I will put all the stuff I want to use in one file and import that.  That will work around JQWidgets using older development practices.